# Convergence is uniform on every compact subset of $\Omega$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of holomorphic functions in $\Omega$ such that $\{f_n(z)\}$ converges for every $z \in \Omega$. Does it necessarily follow that the convergence is uniform on every compact subset of $\Omega$? Here, $\Omega$ denotes a plane open set.

**Idea.** Perhaps we should apply the dominated convergence theorem to the Cauchy formula for $f_n - f_m$?

Answer (score 2):

It is true (assuming that $\Omega$ is an open subset of $\Bbb C$):

Assume that $f_n \to f$ pointwise, but *not uniformly* on a compact
set $K \subset \Omega$. Then there exists an $\varepsilon > 0$,
a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$  of $(f_n)$,
and a sequence $(z_k)$ in $K$ such that
$$ \tag{*}
 |f_{n_k}(z_k) - f(z_k) | \ge \varepsilon \text{ for all } k \in \Bbb N \, .
$$

$(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded, so by [Montel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem) it is [*normal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_family):  $(f_{n_k})$  has a locally uniformly convergent subsequence $(f_{n_{k_l}})$.
In particular, $f_{n_{k_l}} \to f$ uniformly on $K$, which gives
a contradiction to $(*)$.